# KnockoutJs ViewModel function

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

I am new about KnockOutJs and I have this problem.
This is my simple form and I would execute the function Login only when I click on the button.  However, the function is executed when page loads without the user clicking it.
How can I fix it?

```js
$().ready(function() {
      function ViewModel() {        
        var self = this;
        self.username = ko.observable();
        self.password = ko.observable();
        self.Login = function() {          
          console.log('do login');
        };
      }
      ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" data-bind="value:username" placeholder="User Name" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" data-bind="value:password" placeholder="Password" />
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnlogin" data-bind="click:Login()">login</button>
```

Comment: You have to remove the `()` in your `click` binding: you reference the method, not execute it. I.e.: `data-bind="click: Login"`

Comment: You are executing `Login` as soon as the DOM elements are created...hence the alert event without clicking on the button...

Answer (score 3):

Replace the button line by the following:

```
<button type="button" id="btnlogin" data-bind="click:Login">login</button>
```

You are currently executing the Login method on DOM creation, removing the brackets will wait for the click event to be triggered.